# How can i bind an an array to another array in c programming?

Tags: arrays, c, binding

Okay so i wanted to know how would i be able to bind an char type of array called ItemPrefixes to another type of array.
to provide more clarification

i have to create this fruit portal with the use of both functions and arrays.
I have declared both arrays as char itemPrefixes[] and int ItemPrices[]. the shopkeeper will be asked later on about the item prefixes e.g 'A' = apple and the price for the apple being £2. However, i have to first bind the position 'i' in ItemPrefixes and itemPrices arrays to a particular item along with its price. e.g itemPrefixes[0] = 'A' is binded with itemPrices[0] = 2.

Comment: Don't use two arrays, use an array of structures.

Comment: `struct Item { char itemPrefix; int itemPrice; }; struct Item items[SIZE];`

Comment: Seems like if you build both arrays at the same time, the indexes will match. That is, if you always add an ItemPrices when you add an ItemPrefixes and vice versa, as long as neither array is subsequently sorted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can try to use `struct`:

```
struct item {
   char name_item;
   int price;
};
```

then you can create an array of struct

```
struct item my_array[10];
```

you can access the members in this way:

```
my_array[index].name_item;
my_array[index].price;
```

Comment: thanks but i was also wondering is there a way to do it without using struct or is that the only way

Comment: What do you want to do that struct doesn't do?

Comment: you can still use two different arrays and use the same index. but it's better to work with struct.

Comment: i wanted to see if it was doable through a loop but was finding it quite hard with that approach (im a newbie at the c programming language)